# how to get matrix pivot index in C++ eigen

Tags: c++, matrix, pivot, eigen

I want to get matrix pivot index with the C++ linear algebra library eigen, but I do not know which function works, any help will be very appreciated.

assume that X is matrix with dimension of 100*50.
Here is the matrix pivot in R software:

```
qr(X)$pivot
```

and the result is: qr(X)$pivot= 1 2 4 5 7 10 ..(11-41).. 42 45 49 50 3 6 8 9 43 44 46 47 48

Comment: Can you describe what a matrix pivot is better than the R $pivot, since my definition of what a matrix pivot is is dependent on what you are using it for, and R's documentation makes this seem like an incantation.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Matrix X100*50 operation is performed in C++, i want to get '(X.transpose()*X).inverse()', but error is that  singular matrix occurs. Multicollinearity occurs in some columns of matrix, i just want to get non-singular matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get pivoting strategy from permutation matrix, e.g. for qr decomposition

```
ColPivHouseholderQR<MatrixXd> qrA(A);
cout << qrA.colsPermutation().indices() << endl;
```

Comment: It does work, but it is out of my expectation. Here is the matrix `X <<1,1,0,0
     ,1,1,0,0
     ,1,1,0,0
     ,1,1,0,0
     ,1,1,0,0
     ,1,0,2,0
     ,1,0,2,0
     ,1,0,2,0
     ,1,0,2,0
     ,1,0,2,0
     ,1,0,0,3
     ,1,0,0,3
     ,1,0,0,3
     ,1,0,0,3
     ,1,0,0,3
     ,1,0,0,3
     ,1,0,0,3
     ,1,0,0,3
     ,1,0,0,3
     ,1,0,0,3;` and I want to get `pivot=1 2 3 5 4`, which eliminate the back column with multicollinearity of matrix.

Comment: The difference is related to the details of implementation, i.e. selection of the linearly independent set of columns can be done in multiple ways.